# Reactjs form submi

Tags: react

preciso fazer este button submit funcionar alguem pode me ajudar?

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";

const BookingForm = () => {
    
    const handleFormSubmit = () => {console.log("submit")};


return (
    <div>
        <form className="Booking" onSubmit= {() => handleFormSubmit ()} >
            <h1>Booking Request Form</h1>
            <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Your full name" />
            <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Your email" />
            <input type="number" name="phone number"  placeholder="Your phone number" />
           
            <Calendar  />

            <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
);
}
export default BookingForm
```

Answer (score -2):

você está passando handleFormSubmit com arrow function, isso não é necessário. tente utilizar dessa forma:

sua função handle:

```
 const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // aqui é para evitar que o navegador de um refresh...
    console.log("submit")
    };
```

Formas de correção:

```
<form className="Booking" onSubmit= {handleFormSubmit} > // aqui ele vai da refresh

// Aqui não 
<form className="Booking" onSubmit= {(e) => handleFormSubmit(e)} >
```